# python opencv blocked image icon showing when reading image

Tags: python, opencv, camera, logitech

[image: Result of running simple opencv script]

I have a small OpenCV script that works with my windows laptop camera but doesn't work when I plug in an external Logitech C922 Pro HD stream webcam.

I have changed the numbers around in cap = cv2.VideoCapture(xxxNUMBERxxx) to open the camera with no luck. I have also installed the Logitech drivers with no luck. The rest of the internet seems to think it's a permissions issue, but I can't find any specific permission settings so I'm not sure that's the issue. I just want to be able to get a video stream from the camera.

The script is below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Our operations on the frame come here
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
    

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a strange and silly solution. After downloading the 'Logi Capture' app, I had to keep the app running with the video streaming through this app whilst opening up the OpenCV app. Seems like a workaround instead of a solution but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to completely uninstall the Logi Capture application.

Comment: with that info I can finally identify that cursed icon.